# magento not clearing cart after checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, ce-1.9.2.4

I am having problem of magento not clearing cart after checkout.
This only happens with logged in users and with bank transfer payment. Guest user do not face this problem, also with other payment paypal and credit card both guest & logged in user do not face this problem.

Seems it only happens when a logged in user, use bank transfer payment.

Hope someone can advise on how to solve this

I have magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: did you checked log??

Comment: no, how can I do that ?

Comment: go to `var/log` folder then see `system.log` and `exception.log` may be you can find something

Comment: I checked them, and there is noting related to this problem, I made some test purchases today, but there is no log for today, only old logs

Comment: anyone can help :(

Comment: are you using any third party plugin or just magento is there ?